# Split text file into XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a document with chunks of XML data, but in-between each chunk there's plain text. How do I extract just the XML data?

ie

```
blah blah blah
===: text text text :===
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    <Data>
       <Line>information</Line>
       <Line2>more information</Line2>
    </Data>
===: text text text :===
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
===: text text text :===
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
     <Data>
        <Line>2nd information</Line>
        <Line2>more information</Line2>
     </Data>
 ===: text text text :===
 blah blah blah
```

the text withing the ===: :=== will always be different but do not need to be included.

Comment: Be much more specific about those `===: text text text :===` lines, are they literal and always present in that exact same way?

Comment: It'll be different each time, the separator has a time stamp and a bunch of other information

Comment: Still a bit short on info. Can a file start with XML or will there always be a `===: ... :===` line before the first xml?

Comment: Each XML chunk will always start and end with ===: .... :===

Comment: Or each text chunk? That what "text text text" suggests. But maybe that was incorrectly made up. Getting it wrong is an off-by-1 error.

Answer (score 1):

This one here will partition your file by any line that matches `(line.StartsWith("===:") && line.EndsWith(":==="))`.

```
var fs = File.OpenText("file.xml");
var partitions = new List<string>();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
string line;
while ((line = fs.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("===:") && line.EndsWith(":==="))
    {
        if(sb.Length > 0)
            partitions.Add(sb.ToString());
        continue;
    }

    sb.AppendLine(line);
}
 if(sb.Length > 0)
    partitions.Add(sb.ToString());
```

This one builds a partition until it encounters a splitting line, then it starts another partition.

Comment: It'll be different each time, the separator has a time stamp and a bunch of other information

Comment: Add that to the question. This way you are wasting time and goodwill.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Have done now. Not an experienced question asker here soz

Comment: Edited for variable split line.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the indentation try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;



namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "";
            string inputline = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (inputline.Trim().StartsWith("<"))
                {
                    xml += inputline + "\n";
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not every xml line starts with a tag.

Comment: Then post test data that actually represents your input.